# Setting up node-v4.1.0... Heroku always?

Tags: heroku

When i execute any command example heroku logs -t

the command prompt always initialized with Setting up node-v4.1.0...

It takes few minutes to complete it.

This happens even when we do heroku login as well.

Please let me know how to avoid or fix this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue and it was an issue with the computer I was using the command line through.  I aborted the job, restarted the computer and retried the command.  It said that it couldn't read the plugin heroku-apps and reinstalled it.  That resolved the issue.